# I Cant launch place picker

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

Im trying to launch pick placer in my fragment's create view method.

```
    int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

Except the 'this) in the last line is underlined red, and it states ' build android context.Context in intent builder cannot be applied to Fragment '

Does anyone know what I need to change for this to work inside a fragment? thanks

Comment: What if you replace `this` with `getActivity()`? The `build()` method requires an `Activity` rather than a `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `this` with `getActivity()`